# Loading transactional email for different store issue

Tags: magento-1, transactional-mail

I created this file:

```
app/locale/fr_FR/template/email/html/footer.html
```

I want to load it for france. So I went to system->t.emails -> selected the Email-Footer **template** -> select this option value:

```
<option value="fr_FR">French (France)</option>
```

from **locale** and then I pressed the **Load Template** button , but i got the content from:

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/html/footer.html
```

Any idea why ? I am using enterprise version:1.14.3.0.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an entry to your `config.xml` file like shown below.

```
<global>      
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_email_template1 module="SampleModule1">
                <label>ActiveCodeline custom email module</label>
                <file>activecodeline_custom_email1.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_email_template1>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

Change it as per you module naming. above code is just for sample.

Comment: @Attila Naghi accept my answer it you have really solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I didn't have a module for this . Do I have to create a module for each store ? I have more then 20 stores :|

Comment: You have to install fr_FR language pack if not install.

Comment: so i guess the reason why it is not working for me , is that i do not have the fr_FR , de_DE etc languages pack, installed. hmm  interesting :D .

Comment: Yes it should be require.